# Automatically apply indentation using spaces or tabs

Tags: vimrc, indentation

I often edit different files in vim, some of which use tabs, and some and different amounts of spaces.  With this, I have not found a combination of `set expandtab`, `set shiftwidth`, `set softtabstop`, and `filetype plugin indent on` that fit all use cases.  How does one get vim to automatically apply the correct indentation?  Some graphical editors on Windows including Notepad++ would use whatever indentation was present on the prior line, and would work with files that mixed tabs and spaces at different indentation levels, so I am asking if there is a way to implement this functionality in vim without using external plugins.

`

Comment: I'm guessing this is a duplicate question but in the meantime see `:h 'autoindent'`, `:h 'smartindent'`, `:h 'cindent'` for starters. The first one, when enabled, simply uses the indent from the previous line.

Comment: The existence of [Tim Pope's 'vim-sleuth' plugin](https://github.com/tpope/vim-sleuth) implies that a robust native solution may not exist.

Answer (score 3):

If you want vim to analyze the file and automatically find out how many and which indent chars (tabs, spaces) are used you will have to write some code or find a plugin.  To my knowledge there is no such "automatic detection".

**But** there are some partial solutions that might fit your needs:

1. Your files could declare modelines.  That's a special line inside the file you are editing that can set some options (like the ones you mention). See `:help modeline`
2. If you can find a specific pattern about the indent of you files you could write an autocommand.  For example if all your C files use tabs but all python files use 4 spaces and so on. Eg.

   ```
   autocmd FileType c,cpp set noet sw=8
   autocmd FileType python set et sw=4
   ```
3. The ftplugin files can do the same but might be cleaner for more complex code. They are files that are sourced whenever the filetype for a buffer is set. See `:help ftplugins` and `:help ftplugin`.

If you want to find out where an option was last set use `:verbose set OPTION?` (with the question mark!).

Comment: You can also use the `ftplugin` mechanism of vim instead of autcommands